# With unicode-math, some fonts cannot bold with \symbfit when version=bold is set

Tags: unicode-math

The code below are all running with `xelatex` on Windows 10, TeX Live 2022, and have updated all packages by `tlmgr update --all --self`.

```latex
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{XITSMath-Regular.otf}
\setmathfont{XITSMath-Bold.otf}[version=bold]
\begin{document}
$\symbfit{x}$
$x$
\boldmath $x$
\end{document}
```

[image]

XITS Math works. But Erewhon Math, XCharter Math and KpMath not work.

```latex
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Erewhon-Math.otf}
\setmathfont{Erewhon-Math-Bold.otf}[version=bold]
% \setmathfont{XCharter-Math.otf}
% \setmathfont{XCharter-Math-Bold.otf}[version=bold]
% \setmathfont{KpMath-Regular.otf}
% \setmathfont{KpMath-Bold.otf}[version=bold]
\begin{document}
$\symbfit{x}$
$x$
\boldmath $x$
\end{document}
```

[image]

`$\symbfit{x}$` is not bold when `version=bold` is set. But set `BoldFont=` works. I found the usage of `BoldFont` on tex.se, the doc of unicode-math does not mention `BoldFont`.

```latex
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Erewhon-Math.otf}[BoldFont=Erewhon-Math-Bold.otf]
% \setmathfont{XCharter-Math.otf}[BoldFont=XCharter-Math-Bold.otf]
% \setmathfont{KpMath-Regular.otf}[BoldFont=KpMath-Bold.otf]
\begin{document}
$\symbfit{x}$
$x$
\boldmath $x$
\end{document}
```

[image]

What is the reason for this?

## Question:

1. When `\setmathfont{Erewhon-Math-Bold.otf}[version=bold]`, `\setmathfont{XCharter-Math-Bold.otf}[version=bold]` or `\setmathfont{KpMath-Bold.otf}[version=bold]` is set, `$\symbfit{x}$` is not bold. But `$\symbfit{x}$` is bold when `\setmathfont{XITSMath-Bold.otf}[version=bold]`. Why XITSMath works, but Erewhon Math, XCharter Math and KpMath not work.
2. What different between `\setmathfont{Erewhon-Math.otf}[BoldFont=Erewhon-Math-Bold.otf]` and `\setmathfont{Erewhon-Math.otf}\setmathfont{Erewhon-Math-Bold.otf}[version=bold]`?
3. The usage of `BoldFont` is from `fontspec` or other? I cannot found the exactly explanation.

---

## Update

```latex
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{latinmodern-math.otf}
\setmathfont{KpMath-Regular.otf}[version=xxx] % case 1
% \setmathfont{XITSMath-Bold.otf}[version=xxx] % case 2
% \setmathfont{KpMath-Bold.otf}[version=xxx] % case 3
\begin{document}
$\symbfit{x}$
\mathversion{xxx}
$x$
\end{document}
```

In above demo of three case, the first `x` is always latinmodern. Only in case 3, the fisrt `x` is not bold italic. In other words, in case 3, some thing is wrong. At present, the difference between the three cases is that part of the slots in case 3 are empty. I don't know whether this is the reason for this problem. Logically speaking, setting the `version` should not affect any mathematical font if you do not use the `\mathversion{}` to enable version. In other words, the default `normal version` is independent of the other versions set manually. It is not clear whether this problem is caused by defects in the implementation of `unicode-math`.

Comment: I think it is  a `unicode-math` package issue: it has been reported on  `https://github.com/wspr/unicode-math/issues/512` for the Fira-Math fonts… four years ago!

Answer (score 3):

A similar issue has been reported [here](https://github.com/wspr/unicode-math/issues/512) four years ago about Fira-Math fonts, `unicode-math` seems to be a bit frozen…

What is interesting in your post is that the `\symbfit` command works for the XITSMath family and not with the other three you mention. As I am maintaining these three, I tried to understand what is done differently in XITSMath vs. Erewhon-Math. It appears that in XITSMath-Bold defines twice the same glyphs for normal and bold:

- U+0041-U+005A (A-Z upright) and U+1D400-1D419 (bold) hold the same glyphs; idem for the lowercase Latin letters;
- U+1D434-U+1D44D (A-Z italic) and U+1D434-U+1D44D (bold italic) hold the same glyphs;
- and so on…

Doing the same thing on Erewhon-Math-Bold does fix the issue for Erewhon-Math, but this fix looks odd to me : I would expect to put *bolder* versions of U+0041-U+005A (already bold) in U+1D400-1D419 but *not* the same glyphs, I'd rather leave these slots empty if I have no bolder version. Am I wrong?

Regarding your second and third question, my understanding is that the `BoldFont=` is meant for text fonts, not for maths fonts, I am surprised that it works here.

Comment: I agree with you. I think `version`s should be independent and not affected by each other. I updated my question and added an example.